# Can't download app that is compatible with my IPad

Tags: ipad, applications

I was trying to download Call Of Duty Mobile which is compatible on Ipad Mini 2 but I can't download it and says it's not compatible, I checked again and I still can't download it on my Ipad Mini 2

Answer (score 1):

**Call Of Duty Mobile isn’t compatible with iPad Mini 2.**

The [App Store page](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/call-of-duty-mobile/id1287282214) says:

[image: age]

That’s why you won’t be able to download it.

Comment: I think the confusion was from the fact that, in the compatibility list, contrary to the app's description it does list iPad mini 2 as compatable.

Comment: My friend was able to download it on iPhone 6, now I'm confused...